# init_task symbol not found in /proc/kallsyms (kernel 4.5.4-1-ARCH)

Tags: linux-kernel, symbols

I am trying to locate the address of `task_struct` of a thread. First of all, I need to get the address of `task_struct` of the `init_task`, then I iterate the whole list and finally get the `task_struct` of a specific thread. The `task_struct` of the `init_task` can be easily obtained from `/proc/kallsyms` by the command

`grep "\<init_task\>" /proc/kallsyms`.

This worked when I use older kernel version (3.12). But when I switched to newer version (4.5), this idea failed at the very beginning. Because the symbol `init_task` disappears from `/proc/kallsyms`. But when I checked the source code, I can see that the symbol `init_task` is exported (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/init_task.c?v=4.5#L18). Why it doesn't show up in the `/proc/kallsyms`? Or is there any other approach to get the address of `init_task` from user space programs?

Comment: What is the architecture of your machine? Is there any chance it's IA64? Also, look if `CONFIG_ARCH_INIT_TASK` is set to `y` in your kernel `.config`.

Comment: No, my machine is x86_64. And my current version (4.5) of kernel config file has no `CONFIG_ARCH_INIT_TASK` option. I also checked the `.config` file of the old kernel version (3.12) which has `init_task` symbol exported, there is also no such option. It seems that the problem is not because of the `.config` file -:((

Comment: Can you check next two options in your `.config` for new kernel: `CONFIG_UNUSED_SYMBOLS` and `TRIM_UNUSED_KSYMS`? It's unlikely some of them is enabled, but if yes -- it can be the cause.

Comment: Yes, the new kernel has the `CONFIG_UNUSED_SYMBOLS=y`, but no `TRIM_UNUSED_KSYMS` option was found. To my understanding, enabling the `CONFIG_UNUSED_SYMBOLS` option will export unused symbols, that means if the `init_task` is not used, it will be exported anyway. So this doesn't seem to be the cause. Or am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. I see only 2 possible reasons why you are missing `init_task()` symbol: 1. If `CONFIG_ARCH_INIT_TASK=y`  2. `CONFIG_TRIM_UNUSED_KSYMS=y` and symbol is not used in kernel. Probably there is some another mechanism in place that strips unused symbols out, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Thank you Sam Protsenko. Let's wait for some else to see if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling with `CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL` option set.  Without it `kallsyms` seems to include only symbols from `.text` and `init.text` sections: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/link-vmlinux.sh#n152, https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/kallsyms.c#n250